# asp.core2 не работает пример инициализации базы данных из документации microsoft

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

На сайте [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro) в разделе документации asp.core 2, приводится пример инициализации базы данных тестовыми данными.

Сначала я регистрирую контекст базы данных в ConfigureServices с помощью такого кода

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Затем получаю контекст базы данных из контейнера внедрения зависимостей.

```
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).Configure(_ => { }).Build();

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = BuildWebHost(args);

    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        try
        {
            var context = services.GetRequiredService<SchoolContext>();
            DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
        }
    }

    host.Run();
}
```

У меня не работает и я думаю это логично, т.к. метод Main вызывается быстрее метода ConfigureServices и естественно `var context = services.GetRequiredService<SchoolContext>();`
 ничего не вернет.

После запуска получаю ошибку

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'DreamPlace.WebService.Otli.Statistic.Models.SchoolContext' has been registered.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider) ...}
```

Может я чего-то не понял или это действительно ошибка в документации microsoft?

Comment: Что не рабтает то? Какая ошибка? Стектрейс? Сообщение?

Comment: Текст ошибки: No service for type 'DreamPlace.WebService.Otli.Statistic.Models.SchoolContext' has been registered.

Стэк
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)

Comment: 'services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>()' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: Это нужно в текст вопроса вставить, а не в комментарии :)

Comment: Спасибо, добавил к вопросу)

Comment: Вы определенно что то делаете не так - я тлько что прошел по мануалу и все работает.

Comment: Если поставите точку останова на регистрации вашего контекста, вы увидите в стеке вызовов, что контекст регистрируется вот на этой стадии функции Main - ```var host = BuildWebHost(args);```, то есть до попытки получения экземпляра контекста далее в методе Main

Comment: Только ваш метод ```BuildWebHost``` отличается от моего. У меня от выглядит так: ```public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>().Build();```

Comment: Да, вот теперь заработало) Спасибо!

Действительно всё дело в BuildWebHost, у меня он отличается, т.к. я вручную делаю миграцию с asp.core 1

Comment: Пожалуйста. Рад, что помогло

Answer (score 4):

Как указал [tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179763/tym32167), у меня неверный метод `BuildWebHost`. Правильный вариант:

```
IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) => 
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Bui‌​ld();
```

Comment: @tym32167 в ответах не работает обращение через @, а для выделения внутристрочного кода достаточно одного бэктика. (А три — это code fence, синтаксис из github flavoured markdown).

Comment: @NickVolynkin я уже столько лет пользуюсь тремя, что делаю это на автомате. Да и выглядит с этим @ более понятно, что это не просто текст, а вроде как логический референс на юзера. Я за единообразие, в общем :)

Comment: @tym32167 markdown штука такая, много диалектов. Когда вы ставите три бэктика, вы на самом деле открываете, закрываете и снова открываете блок. :)